# What is a formula to sum a row based on criteria in a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a sheet in **Google Sheets** for items in a video game called *EVE Online*, for what that matters. Each item in `Sheet1` can be "reprocessed" into basic minerals. Each item in `Sheet2` lists the basic minerals.

In `Sheet1!A1`, I have "Item Name."
`Sheet1!A2:A251` is items.
`Sheet1!B1` is "Reprocessed."

`Sheet2!A1` is "Item Name."
`Sheet2!A2:A251` is the same items from `Sheet1`, copied and pasted over.
`Sheet2!B1:AG1` is mineral names.
`Sheet2!B2:AG251` is numbers of specific minerals the items can be reprocessed into.

In `Sheet1!B2`, I want to put a formula that will look at the item name in `Sheet1!A2`, find the corresponding item in `Sheet2`, and sum that row.

I have tried:

`=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet2!$B:$AG)`

This yields a sum of zero, where the sum of the numbers I have for `Sheet2!A2` (the numbers in `Sheet2!B2:AG2`) should be 23,587.

Comment: Here is a blank you and @Broly can use
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1opB0GUeS4AsOu3k5wpE6M9GUbP8EM3VCwVbiyNysSWU/edit

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what your data looks like I have prepared a sample data based on what you shared in the question.

If your `Sheet2` looks like this:
[image]

then use the formula `=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&MATCH(A2, Sheet2!A:A, 1)&":"&MATCH(A2, Sheet2!A:A, 1)))` in `Sheet1!B2` and it should work as shown below

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting a result of zero. I'm not sure how I can share my data, but let me know and I'll see if I can upload it somehow.

Comment: You can create a new sheet or use the one commented by @MattKing above. Please do not share sensitive or PII data under any circumstances .